# How to convert string with mix of upper and lower case randomly

Tags: javascript

I would like to convert the string with a mix of upper and lower case. For example, if I have string `Mark`, I need an output as `mARk`, or `Lewis` to convert as `lEwIs`. How can I achieve this in vanilla JavaScript?

**Note:** The rule of conversion is random.

I've tried `Camelize` function, but that not giving me an expected output:

```
function camelize(str) {
  return str.replace(/(?:^\w|[A-Z]|\b\w)/g, function(letter, index) {
    return index === 0 ? letter.toLowerCase() : letter.toUpperCase();
  }).replace(/\s+/g, '');
}
```

Comment: What is the logic that determines `Mark` should be `mARk`, but that `Lewis` should become `lEwIs`?

Comment: `Array.from(str).map(v => Math.random()>.5 ? v.toUpperCase() : v.toLowerCase()).join('')`?

Comment: Hi All - It should be random

Comment: In that case @Denys comment should do the trick and need to get more up-votes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick.  Edited to make random

```
function flipCase(str) { 
  var flip = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if(Math.random() > .5){
      flip += str.charAt(i).toUpperCase();
    } else {
      flip += str.charAt(i).toLowerCase();
    }
  }
  return flip;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you mentioned in comments that you wanted it to be random, but for other readers who are looking for a function to invert the casing, here is one way of doing it:

```js
function camelize(str) {
  var inverted = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str.charCodeAt(i) >= 65 && str.charCodeAt(i) <= 90)
      inverted += str.charAt(i).toLowerCase();
    else
      inverted += str.charAt(i).toUpperCase();
  }
  return inverted;
}

console.log(camelize("Mark"));
console.log(camelize("Lwies"));
```

And here is another way using `Array.map()`:

```js
function camelize(str) {
  return Array.from(str).map(l => (l.charCodeAt(0) >= 65 && l.charCodeAt(0) <= 90) ? l.toLowerCase() : l.toUpperCase()).join('');
}

console.log(camelize("Mark"));
console.log(camelize("Lwies"));
```